# Does "print $ARGV" alter the argument array in any way?

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments, argv, shift

Here is the example:

```
$a = shift; 
$b = shift; 
push(@ARGV,$b); 
$c = <>; 

print "\$b: $b\n"; 
print "\$c: $c\n"; 
print "\$ARGV: $ARGV\n"; 
print "\@ARGV: @ARGV\n";
```

And the output:

```
$b: file1 
$c: dir3 

$ARGV: file2 
@ARGV: file3 file1
```

I don't understand what exactly is happening when printing $ARGV without any index. Does it print the first argument and then remove it from the array? Because I thought after all the statements the array becomes:

```
file2 file3 file1
```

Invocation:

```
perl port.pl -axt file1 file2 file3
```

file1 contains the lines:

```
dir1 
dir2
```

file2:

```
dir3 
dir4 
dir5
```

file3:

```
dir6 
dir7
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Greg has quoted the appropriate documentation, so here's a quick rundown of what happens

```
$a = shift;                 # "-axt" is removed from @ARGV and assigned to $a
$b = shift;                 # "file1" likewise
push(@ARGV,$b);             # "file1" inserted at end of @ARGV
$c = <>;                    # "file2" is removed from @ARGV, and its file
                            # handle opened, the first line of file2 is read
```

When the file handle for "file2" is opened, it sets the file name in `$ARGV`. As Greg mentioned, `@ARGV` and `$ARGV` are completely different variables.

The internal workings of the diamond operator `<>` is probably what is confusing you here, in that it does an  approximate `$ARGV = shift @ARGV`

Comment: oh I see, yeah I was still wondering about how the argument was removed from the array. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In Perl, `$ARGV` and `@ARGV` are completely different. From [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

> ## $ARGV
>
> Contains the name of the current file when reading from `<>`.
>
> ## @ARGV
>
> The array `@ARGV` contains the command-line arguments intended for the script. `$#ARGV` is generally the number of arguments minus one, because `$ARGV[0]` is the first argument, not the program's command name itself. See `$0` for the command name.

Answer (score 4):

No, but `<>` does. `<>` is short for `<ARGV>` (which in turn is short for `readline(ARGV)`)
, where `ARGV` is a special file handle that reads from the files listed in `@ARGV` (or `STDIN` if `@ARGV` is empty). As it opens the files in `@ARGV`, it removes them from `@ARGV` and stores them in `$ARGV`.